# What kind of join should I implement in order to receive the output I am trying to get?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

NOTE: Just a practice problem.. NOT looking for free homework answers.

The practice problem I have asks to **report the number of flights by plane’s year in ascending order of plane’s year**. This requires the joining of two tables, the flights table and planes table. I believe the SQL should be relatively simple, and I think the main issue with mine is the vague select statement I currently have. I have looked at the different join methods, both explicit and implicit, and have also tried a left join with no luck.

If more table information is needed, I can share. The column the two tables share is year.

Also, very new here, so if there is something undesirable or incorrect about this post, please let me know.

```
select *,  
count(*) as n_flights  
from flights, planes 
where flights.year = planes.year 
order by planes.year asc 
;
```

The output I am looking for:
[image]

The output I get:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, there is a column in the flights table that refers to the primary key of the planes table - let me assume `plane_id`: this is what you would use to join the tables.

Then, you want to aggregate by plane year, using a `group by` clause, and count the number of rows in each group:

```
select p.year, count(*) as n_flights  
from flights f
inner join planes p on p.plane_id = f.plane_id
group by p.year 
order by p.year
```

Comment: This worked when I changed plane_id to tailnum as that is what is shared between the two tables, which I understand is still what you meant! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select planes.year, count(*) 
from flights, planes 
where flights.year = planes.year 
group by planes.year
order by planes.year asc
```

Comment: This only returns the year and count(*), with only one value returned for each of them. I always appreciate extra answers and different insights, so nonetheless, thanks!!